# Equivalent of $('selector').Position in angular when DOM's value is empty

Tags: angular, dom

I'm about to adjust position of an element based on another element. and need to know the `left` value of other element. The problem is: DOM object has empty value for `left` property of style, And i just can't get the source element position.
assume some thing like this:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  ...
  ShowDropdownContent(dropdown){
    console.log(dropdown.style.left);//Loggs an empty string.
  }
  ...
}
```

Meanwhile in `jquery` we simply call: `$('SomeSelector').position().left`.
Has `angular` any equivalent of this? (specially when DOM's left value of element is empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the getBoundingClientRect() function on the nativeElement:

```
<select #dropdown>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
 @ViewChild("dropdown") dropdown:ElementRef;
 constructor() {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // viewChild is set after the view has been initialized
    const rect = this.dropdown.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.left);
  }
}
```

Comment: `offsetLeft` did the job but `computedStyle.left` didn't. why is that?

Comment: computedStyle gets the left value set by css. If there isn't any css setting the left property it wont return the right value. offsetLeft is position left+margin from the first positioned parent left edge.

Comment: correction! `offsetLeft` returns offset from left and does not change if horizontally scrolled. So there is no match for `$.Position`. what a shame!

Comment: what about this.dropdown.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left ?

Comment: indeed works! please edit your answer adding `getBoundingClientRect` so i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `style` property references the `style` attribute of an element.

See for yourself.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(div.style.background);
console.log(div.style.border);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: red"></div>
```

Rely on `getComputedStyle` to get the style.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

const computed = window.getComputedStyle(div);

console.log(computed.getPropertyValue('background'));
console.log(computed.getPropertyValue('border'));
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: red"></div>
```

Comment: By the way, manipulating the DOM yourself is bad practice in Angular, so avoid that if you can.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this time left property is "0". meanwhile it should be around "150px".

Comment: Since you saw it working in the snippet, you will need to provide a [mcve] for me to test it.